# How do I get rid of flickering image and clear previous canvas result using canvas html5?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am using  of html5 to draw the human pose key points on the black image using drawImage(). When I upload a video for the first time it draws properly. But when I upload the second video the result of the previous video is retained as well as current video results in the flickering of the image while being drawn. Find below the code -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      let fileURL;
      let file_ext;
      let width, height; 
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var image_bg;//document.getElementById('source');
      let video;

      // The detected positions will be inside an array
      let poses = [];
      let poseNet;
      

      $("#selectVideoFile").filestyle({htmlIcon: '<span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>&nbsp;',
        size: "md",
        text: ' Select',
        btnClass : "btn btn-change",
        placeholder: "Upload person video"          
      });

      function isEmpty(obj) {
        for(var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
      }

      function showInpVideo(input) {
        if (!(isEmpty(fileURL))) {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);  
        }
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('selectVideoFile');
        fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);

        $('#inputVideo').html("");
        $('#inputVideo').append('<video controls id="video" src="'+ fileURL +'" alt="Input Video" width="620" height="360"></video>');                
      };

      

      // Listen for the change event on our input element so we can 
        // get the video file selected by the user
      document.getElementById('selectVideoFile').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                    
          var fileName = $(".vidFile").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
          file_ext = (fileName !== '') ? fileName.split(".")[1].toLowerCase() : '';
      
          console.log('Video File extension: ', file_ext);
          
          $('#inputVideo').html("");
          $('#canvasVideo').html("");
              
          console.log('On change video name: ', fileName);
          
          $('.input-video-loader').hide();
          // $('.processed-video-loader').hide();
          $('#inputVideo').hide();
          $('.caption-text-video-input').hide();
          $('.caption-text-video-processed').hide();
          $('#canvas').hide();
          $('#displayVideos').hide();
          $('#videoBtn').hide();
        
          // If file is selected or file selected has extension mp4

          if (($('#selectVideoFile').val() !== '') && (file_ext === 'mp4')) {
        
            $('#displayVideos').show();
            $('.caption-text-video-input').show();
            $('.input-video-loader').show();
            $('#inputVideo').show();
              
            // Show input video
            showInpVideo();
              
            $('.input-video-loader').hide();
            
            vidId  = document.getElementById('video');
            console.log('video: ', vidId);
            height = $('#video').height();
            width = $('#video').width();
            
            mdlSetup(vidId);

              
            console.log(width+' '+height);
            
            
        
        } else {
            $('#displayVideos').hide();
            alert("Please upload person video file having extension -- (.mp4)!")
            $('#selectVideoFile').val('');
          }
        });
        
        function mdlSetup(vidId){
            console.log('***  Model Setup  ****');
            video = vidId;      
            
            //Posenet
            poseNet = ml5.poseNet(video, modelReady);           
            console.log('Model Loaded ');
            poseNet.on('pose', gotPoses);
        }

      
      // A function to draw the video and poses into the canvas.
      // This function is independent of the result of posenet
      // This way the video will not seem slow if poseNet 
      // is not detecting a position
      function drawVideoIntoCanvas() {
        //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 620, 360);
        // console.log('Draw Canvas: ', ctx);       

        // Draw the video element into the canvas
        ctx.drawImage(image_bg, 0, 0, 620, 360);
        // We can call both functions to draw all keypoints and the skeletons
        drawKeypoints();
        drawSkeleton();
        requestAnimationFrame(drawVideoIntoCanvas);
      }

      // A function that gets called every time there's an update from the model
      function gotPoses(results) {
        poses = results;
        //console.log('Poses : ', poses)
      
      }

      function modelReady() {
        // document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Model Loaded'
        console.log("model ready")
        poseNet.multiPose(video);
      }

      // A function to draw ellipses over the detected keypoints
      function drawKeypoints()  {      
        // Loop through all the poses detected
        for (let i = 0; i < poses.length; i=i+2) {
        // For each pose detected, loop through all the keypoints
        for (let j = 0; j < poses[i].pose.keypoints.length; j++) {
          let keypoint = poses[i].pose.keypoints[j];
          // Only draw an ellipse is the pose probability is bigger than 0.2
          if (keypoint.score > 0.2) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(0, ' + Math.floor(255 - 42.5 * i) + ', ' + 
                      Math.floor(255 - 42.5 * j) + ')';
          //ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
          ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(17, 240, 110)';
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(keypoint.position.x, keypoint.position.y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.stroke();
          }
         }
        } 
      }

      // A function to draw the skeletons
      function drawSkeleton() {
        // Loop through all the skeletons detected
        for (let i = 0; i < poses.length; i=i+2) {
          // For every skeleton, loop through all body connections
          for (let j = 0; j < poses[i].skeleton.length; j++) {
            let partA = poses[i].skeleton[j][0];
            let partB = poses[i].skeleton[j][1];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(partA.position.x, partA.position.y);
            ctx.lineTo(partB.position.x, partB.position.y);
          ctx.lineWidth = 2;
          
          // set line color
          ctx.strokeStyle = '#13f0c7'
            ctx.stroke();
          }
        }
      }

      // video button controls
    $('#play-btn').click(function(){
      video.play();
    });

    $('#stop-btn').click(function() {
      video.pause();
    });

    $('#reload-btn').click(function(){
      video.load();
    });
    
    $('#refresh-btn').click(function(){
        window.location.reload(true);
    })
        
  // on submit button click show canvas.
    $('#btnVideoSubmit').click(function() {
      
        console.log('-------On Execute Button Click-------');
        console.log(width + ' ' + height);
        console.log('video after sbmit: ', video);
        // $('.processed-video-loader').show();
                
        if (($('#selectVideoFile').val() !== '') && (file_ext === 'mp4')){
                        
            $('.caption-text-video-processed').show();
            $('#canvas').show();
            $('#videoBtn').show(200);
            
            image_bg = new Image();
            image_bg.onload = function(){
                drawVideoIntoCanvas();
            };
            image_bg.src = 'https://www.ehotelsasia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Black-Background-DX58.jpg';
            console.log('image_bg src:', image_bg.src);
            

            // Loop over the drawVideoIntoCanvas function
            //drawVideoIntoCanvas(); 
        } else {
          $('#displayVideos').hide();
          alert("Please upload person video file having extension -- (.mp4)!")
        }
    })


  
/// --------------------- End -----------------------
//document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function(){
    //ctx.clearRect(image_bg, 0, 0, 640, 375);
//})

});
```

Comment: You need to cancel the playing animation loop before you start a new one. Use `cancelAnimationFrame(frameRequestHandle)` to cancel frame request. The frame request handle is returned by `requestAnimationFrame` eg `frameRequestHandle = requestAnimationFrame(callback)`

Comment: So @Blindman67 where shall I add cancelAnimationFrame() exactly in the code? Kindly help.

Comment: Hi, @Blindman67 kindly find the updated code here. I tried many versions but not getting proper results. Please help me with this code. I will be really thankful to you. Here is the link - https://pastebin.com/qU0uqxwe

Comment: Add at top after first line. `var rAFHdl ;` then in function `drawVideoIntoCanvas` change last line to  `rAFHdl = requestAnimationFrame(drawVideoIntoCanvas);` then change the   `image_bg.onload` function to `image_bg.onload = function() { cancelAnimationFrame(rAFHdl ); drawVideoIntoCanvas();}`

Comment: Hi, @Blindman67I tried the same as you guided but it didn't work out. Here is the corrected code - [https://pastebin.com/1gn5A63m]. If you don't mind can we connect via skype?